# NatTable Filtering

Tags: java, nattable

I am trying to simultaneously apply two different types of filtering to a NatTable.  Each filter works fine on its own but they do not work as I expected when they are combined.

- The first thing I do is make a call to the FilterList.setMatcher() to reduce the number of rows based on external criteria
- The next thing I do is use the FilterRowHeaderComposite to apply further filtering, but it seems to ignore the input (even though I see the input/icon in the filter header cell) and no filter is applied

Below is some basic code snippets that show what I have setup...

```
public void basicSetup() {
    eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(values);
    TransformedList<T, T> rowObjectsGlazedList = GlazedLists.
      threadSafeList(eventList);
    sortedList = new SortedList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList, myComparator<>());
    filterList = new FilterList<>(sortedList);

    //... code ommitted

    FilterRowHeaderComposite<T> filterRowHeaderLayer = new 
      FilterRowHeaderComposite<>(
            new DefaultGlazedListsFilterStrategy<T>(bodyLayerStack.
              getFilterList(), columnPropertyAccessor, configRegistry),
            sortHeaderLayer, columnHeaderDataLayer.getDataProvider(), 
            configRegistry);

}

public void applyExternalFilter() {
    getBodyLayerStack().getFilterList().setMatcher(myCriteria);
}

public void resetExternalFilter() {
    getBodyLayerStack().getFilterList().setMatcher(null);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix programmatic applied filters with user applied filters via filter row. This does not work that way as the filter row deals with the matchers on the `FilterList` and it is not possible to identify which filters are added by whom.

To support mixing static filters with user defined filters you need to use the `DefaultGlazedListsStaticFilterStrategy` that supports adding additional static filters.

An example is available in the *NatTable Examples Application -> Tutorial Examples -> GlazedLists -> Filter -> GlazedListsStaticFilterExample* (_6033_GlazedListsStaticFilterExample.java)

```
DefaultGlazedListsStaticFilterStrategy filterStrategy = new DefaultGlazedListsStaticFilterStrategy(
                    bodyLayerStack.getFilterList(),
                    columnPropertyAccessor,
                    configRegistry);

FilterRowHeaderComposite filterRowHeaderLayer =
        new FilterRowHeaderComposite(
                filterStrategy,
                columnHeaderLayer,
                columnHeaderDataLayer.getDataProvider(),
                configRegistry);
```

A static filter can then be applied via

```
filterStrategy#addStaticFilter(Matcher);
```

Currently there is no clear method available. It is only possible to remove a previous applied filter. But feel free to create an enhancement ticket for clearing and provide a patch.